# want to make recommendation with Spark mlib with rdd from orientdb

Tags: orientdb, apache-spark-mllib

I want to get vertices and edges from orientDB graph and make a recommendations with Spark MLIB how can i do it? i don't know how transform the vertices to an RDD to work with it

```
package com.mycompany.sparkorientdbdemo
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import com.metreta.spark.orientdb.connector._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
object Demo extends App {
val conf = new SparkConf()
.setMaster("local[*]")
.setAppName("OrientDBConnectorTest")
.set("spark.orientdb.clustermode", "remote")
.set("spark.orientdb.connection.nodes", "localhost")
.set("spark.orientdb.protocol", "remote")
.set("spark.orientdb.dbname", "Insta")
.set("spark.orientdb.port", "2424")
.set("spark.orientdb.user", "admin")
.set("spark.orientdb.password", "admin")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val graphInsta = sc.orientGraph()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: how can i make a Mchine learning to working with this graph ?